# Simulating multiple-inheritance in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am working on a project that basically requires multiple-inheritance in the formal sense:

```
class X
class Y

class XY extends X,Y
```

I have two classes which have some definitions and are used throughout code, i.e:

```
def alpha(x: X)
def beta(y: Y)
```

I want to dynamically create a class `XY` which is just merges all definitions from `X` and `Y` but still retains the type-safety. More specifically that the previously defined `alpha` and `beta` still accept this merged class.

I know that Scala allows mixing in traits, for example:

```
trait T
class A

val ta = new A with T
```

That works fine.

However, I cannot do it with classes:

```
class X
class Y

val xy = new X with Y
```

As the `with ..` must be a trait.

I have tried circumventing this by doing the following:

```
trait xV extends X
trait yV extends Y

val xy = new xV with yV
```

Unfortunately this does not work and gives the following error:

```
Error:(33, 26) illegal inheritance; superclass X
 is not a subclass of the superclass Y
 of the mixin trait yV
    val xy = new xV with yV
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

To clarify, I **cannot** modify classes `X` or `Y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this literally is impossible. But

> More specifically that the previously defined alpha and beta still accept this merged class.

This specific requirement can be achieved by using implicit conversions:

```
class XY {
  val x = new X
  val y = new Y
}

object XY {
  implicit def toX(xy: XY): X = xy.x
  implicit def toY(xy: XY): Y = xy.y
}
```

You'll also be able to call `X`'s and `Y`'s methods directly.

But e.g. `xy match { case x: X => ...` won't match, and similarly `xy.isInstanceOf[X]` will be false. If `X` or `Y` override any of the `Object` methods: `equals`, `hashCode`, or `toString`, they won't be inherited by `XY`.

Comment: This may actually be super useful. I'll report back. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well it seems like this solution works to some extent... But, is there any way to make `toX` conversion take precedence over `toY`?

Comment: Yes, just move `toY` into a trait which `object XY` extends.

Answer (score 2):

Scala does not have the multiple inheritance C++ style, in order to avoid the dreaded [Diamond Shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) inheritance pattern.

The (only) [solution](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/mixin-class-composition) provided by Scala is to provide mixins in the form of `Trait`s. To resolve method implementation conflicts, the last Trait implemented (the one the most to the right) is chosen.

So unless, at least one of `X` or `Y` is a Trait, `A` will not be able to inherit (methods) from both